# How to make a timer that outputs on one line

Tags: c#, timer, user-input

At the moment I have made a timer that outputs on multiple lines like this:[image]

However, if the user chooses 1000 seconds that would take too much space.

I need a way so that it changes the first line to the number below automatically.

Here is my timer code:

```
public class TimerExample
{
    static int UserInputs()
    {
        int numberOfSeconds;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many seconds would you like the test to be? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfSeconds);
        } while (numberOfSeconds % 10 != 0);
        return numberOfSeconds;
    }
    public class TimerClass
        {
            public static int Timers(int timeLeft)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"timeLeft: {timeLeft}");
                    timeLeft--;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (timeLeft > 0);
                return timeLeft;
            }
        }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfSeconds = UserInput();
        TimerClass.Timers(numberOfSeconds);
    }
}
```

Here is my full code if you need it:
https://github.com/CrazyDanyal1414/mathstester

Comment: Use `Console.Write` instead `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: @bradbury9 `Console.Write()` will provide an output such as `10987654321` if user enters 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the count down to be shown on the same line then you can change the below line

```
Console.WriteLine($"timeLeft: {timeLeft}");
```

to

```
Console.Write("\rtimeLeft: {0}   ", timeLeft);
```

Hopefully that does the trick for you. \r will re-write the same line

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. I've just indented your code with 4 spaces to enable the syntax coloring.

Comment: You can also format it nicely using: ```cs

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use:

1. Console.Write and not Console.WirteLine
2. Use "\r" at the start of your print so you override the line instead of append the data to the line

---

**Here some code to test:**

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\r" + i);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```